# Robot_pose_ekf does not take into account the velocity commands

Tags: navigation, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Im also ROS users and doing some research in assist robotics. Im using Fuerte and Ubuntu 10.04. Have somee problem with the robot_pose_ekf package. My platform has wheel encoders and IMU , laser and Kinect.
So when using the robot_pose_ekf package it does not take into account the velocity commands sent to the robot when updating the filter. I have topics from encoders contains velocity massages but robot_pose_ekf it does not take into account.

So I though to modify  the code of the robot_pose_ekf stack and add the velocity information. I'm not sure if that's possible. I've looked the code and seems that it only works with poses, but I'm not sure.

I already have an node for subscribe to odom topic. This my node

```
void odomCallback(const nav_msgs::OdometryConstPtr& msg)
{
  //first, we'll publish the transform over tf
    odom_trans.transform.translation.x = odom_raw.pose.pose.position.x  =  msg->pose.pose.position.x;
    odom_trans.transform.translation.y = odom_raw.pose.pose.position.y  =  msg->pose.pose.position.y;

    odom_trans.transform.rotation = odom_raw.pose.pose.orientation = msg->pose.pose.orientation;

odom_raw.twist = msg->twist;
    


        odom_trans.header.stamp = odom_raw.header.stamp = msg->header.stamp;
        pub2.publish(odom_raw);
    

    static tf::TransformBroadcaster br;
   
    
}

void poseCallback(const geometry_msgs::PoseWithCovarianceStampedConstPtr& msg)
{
  odom.pose.pose.position.x = msg->pose.pose.position.x;
  odom.pose.pose.position.y = msg->pose.pose.position.y;
  odom.pose.pose.orientation = msg->pose.pose.orientation;
  odom.header.stamp = msg->header.stamp;


//Speed calculation
  delta_t = ros::Time::now().toSec() - time_last;
  odom.twist.twist.linear.x = (msg->pose.pose.position.x-xlast)/delta_t;
  odom.twist.twist.linear.y = (msg->pose.pose.position.y-ylast)/delta_t;
  curr_yaw = tf::getYaw(msg->pose.pose.orientation);
  odom.twist.twist.angular.z = normalize(curr_yaw-yaw_last)/delta_t;

  pub.publish(odom);
  xlast = msg->pose.pose.position.x; ylast = msg->pose.pose.position.y; yaw_last = curr_yaw;
  time_last = ros::Time::now().toSec();
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

 
  ros::init(argc, argv, "ekf_encoders_odom");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  initialize();

  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe("odom", 1, odomCallback);

  pub2 = nh.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("raw_odometry", 1);

  ros::Rate rate(1);
  while(ros::ok())
{
  ros::spinOnce();
  rate.sleep();
}
return 0;
}
```

So do I need something else???

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58665/robot_pose_ekf-does-not-take-into-account-the-velocity-commands/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Example how to generate Odometry message from encoders.

```
#include "pr2_mechanism_model/joint.h"
#include "pr2_controller_interface/controller.h"
#include "nav_msgs/Odometry.h"
#include "sensor_msgs/JointState.h"
#include "tf/transform_broadcaster.h"
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "math.h"


double delta_x = 0;
double delta_y = 0;
double delta_a1 = 0;
double delta_a2 = 0;
double fi = 0;
double current_fi = 0;
double last_x = 0;
double last_y = 0;
double current_a1, current_a2;
double last_a1 = 0;
double last_a2 = 0;


void OdomCallback(const sensor_msgs::JointState::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  // Getting the positions of right and left back wheels from /joint_states topic 

  current_a1 = msg->position[4];
  current_a2 = msg->position[5];

}


int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "odom_publisher");

    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher odom_pub;
    ros::Subscriber odom_sub;

    odom_sub = n.subscribe("/joint_states",1000,OdomCallback);



    odom_pub = n.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("odom",100);
    tf::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster;

      ros::Rate r(1.0);

      ros::Time current_time, last_time;
      current_time = ros::Time::now();
      last_time = ros::Time::now();

      double  R = 0.07; //wheel radius
      double d = 0.3;  //distance between two wheels
      double x = 0;     //initial values
      double y = 0;
      double th = 0;
      double vx, vy, vth;

      int count = 0;
      while(n.ok())
      {
            ros::spinOnce();               // check for incoming messages
            current_time = ros::Time::now();

            delta_a1 = current_a1 - last_a1;
            delta_a2 = current_a2 - last_a2;

            last_a1 = current_a1;
            last_a2 = current_a2;
            //ROS_INFO("delta_a %f", delta_a);
            double dt = (current_time - last_time).toSec();

            current_fi = -R*(delta_a2 - delta_a1)/d;
            fi +=current_fi;
            current_fi = 0;
            ROS_INFO("yaw %f", fi);

            delta_x = R*delta_a1*cos(fi);
            delta_y = R*delta_a1*sin(fi);


            x += delta_x;
            y += delta_y;
            th = fi;
            vx = delta_x/dt;
            vy = delta_y/dt;
            vth = current_fi/dt;


            //since all odometry is 6DOF we'll need a quaternion created from yaw
               geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);

               //first, we'll publish the transform over tf
               geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;
               odom_trans.header.stamp = current_time;
               odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
               odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";

               odom_trans.transform.translation.x = -x;
               odom_trans.transform.translation.y = -y;
               odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0;
               odom_trans.transform.rotation = odom_quat;

               //send the transform
               odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);

               //next, we'll publish the odometry message over ROS
               nav_msgs::Odometry odom;
               odom.header.stamp = current_time;
               odom.header.frame_id = "odom";

               //set the position
               odom.pose.pose.position.x = -x;
               odom.pose.pose.position.y = -y;
               odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
               odom.pose.pose.orientation = odom_quat;

               //set the velocity
               odom.child_frame_id = "base_link";
               odom.twist.twist.linear.x = vx;
               odom.twist.twist.linear.y = vy;
               odom.twist.twist.angular.z = vth;

               //publish the message
               odom_pub.publish(odom);

               last_time = current_time;
               r.sleep();
               count++;
      }

 return 0;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) with karma: 338 on 2013-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2